# SQL subquery Case statement

Tags: sql

I am working on the following SQL:

```
select a.field1 a.field2 b.field3

(select FIELD from table3 where KEY = a.field1) as field4

from TAB1 a inner join TAB2 b on a.key = b.key.
```

My requirement is display value of FIELD FROM table3 if there is a entry else 'N/A' in field4. I am trying the following and receiving error "NTO clause not allowed for this SELECT statement: subquery is not allowed here"

Any pointers on how can i achieve this...

```
select a.field1 a.field2 b.field3 
case when (select FIELD into lv_value from TABLE3 where TABLE3.KEY = a.key) is null then 'N/A'
else.
lv_value
end as field4 
from TAB1 a inner join TAB2 b on TAB1.KEY = TAB2.KEY.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that you can directly express it via standard function `coalesce()`:

```
select a.field1 a.field2 b.field3
       coalesce( (select t3.FIELD 
                  from table3 t3
                  where t3.KEY = a.field1
                  ), 'N/A'
               ) as field4
from TAB1 a 
inner join TAB2 b on a.key = b.key;
```

Be aware, from `subquery` error while you have more records for single *key* if so, then use `LIMIT` clause or `TOP` whichever your *DBMS* has support with appropriate `order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks , Yogesh. I made this change and was able to see desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You should join the TABLE3 with your query instead of a sub query with left join. And you can use ISNULL function -if you are using SQL Server - with it, the result should be like this;

```
select a.field1, a.field2, b.field3, ISNULL(c.lv_value , 'N/A') as field4 
from TAB1 a inner join TAB2 b on TAB1.KEY = TAB2.KEY LEFT JOIN TABLE3 c ON c.KEY = a.KEY
```

Comment: `ISNULL()` is `SQL Server` specific.

Comment: You can also use `coalesce()` which is `SQL` Standard will work in almost all DBMS.